# Why can't I get any proper arcs out of this flyback transformer?

Tags: mosfet, transformer, high-voltage, mosfet-driver, flyback

I salvaged a flyback transformer from an old TV and used it in a single MOSFET driver like this:

[image: Driver circuit]

I used  6 turns of insulated copper wire to make the primary coil with the centre tap and again 6 turns. I found the secondary ground on the flyback and tried drawing some arcs, but to my disappointment all what I got was a 2 mm arc.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening and if there is a way of correcting my circuit for larger arcs?

Answer (score 3):

use fewer turns for the primary, like 3 perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

As Jasen mentioned in his answer use fewer turns, 3 to 6. Bring the voltage up to as high as 24. Plan on mounting Q1 to a large heatsink. You should be able to get arcs of 1/2" (12.7mm). You could get 1 inch arcs but Q1 will get hot - and you risk the transformer arcing internally.

Comment: In the Youtube video I learnt this from, the circuit gave about 1 cm arcs at around 5 volts.I have tried feeding 18v with no better results.Do you think the is a problem with my flyback transformer?

Comment: Not at all, unless you hear internal arcing. Always give it something to arc to so the voltage does not get so high it arcs within the transformer and destroys it. Minimum turns should be 3, but I have always used 6 so the MOSFET sees a minimum safe load. With 6 turns 18 volts might work. Also do not over drive the MOSFET gate. R1 can be as high as 1K.

Comment: @VTNCaGNtdDVNalUyI have not included the resistor in my circuit.Will there be any problem if I dont?

Comment: Without R1 you will overload the gate and destroy the MO(SFET. MOSFETs have gate protection diodes built-in but need the current limiting a resistor provides. It can be as high as 1 Kohm. This will allow you to safely drive T1 with more voltage.

Answer (score 0):

There is a flat in the Schema. You have to connect the Battery to the middle contact of the Coil. And the Drain has to be there where the Battery was.